# Retrieving Credit Card Information From Passbook Using iOS8

Tags: ios8, passbook, passkit

I googled the PassKit framework for iOS 8 APIs but was unable to find any APIs that retrieves the Credit Card details from the Passbook application. Apple says we can store our Card details in iOS 8 Passbook. Can we retrieve the card details such as (card number, expiry date, CCV) from the new iOS8 Passkit ?

I need to retrieve the card details from the Passbook and further send it to the Payment Gateway, without the user manually entering the details of the card.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access individual credit card details like card number, expiry date, cvv from your app - because these are not actually stored on the phone. Only a token representing the card information is stored on the chip.

If you want to request a user to authorise apple Pay, you should present a PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController from your view controller. You should pass your payment request (PKPaymentRequest) to this controller, containing the amount, currency, item etc. It will present an action sheet showing the payment/shipping details along with the 'pay with touch id' option.

I've tried this in the Simulator and unfortunately I can only see 'Null, null' in the card section. I'm not sure how to add a test card to Passbook. Have you been able to do that?

Comment: If suppose I do not want Apple Pay. Can I use this token and send to any Payment Gateway say STRIPE and further initiate a payment ?